# pandas: Explode (duplicate) by group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': ["idx1"],
    'test_A': ["ABC", ],
    'test_B': ["X"],
    'test_C': ["ABC / XYZ"],
    'test_D': ["ABC / JKL / XYZ"]})
```

It's an example for one row but there are thousands of rows.
I want to explode each value where there are multiple values in these four "TEST" columns ie. I want each one to duplicate the row for each one of the "test" that is the same and if there are many (separed by a "/") i want to duplicate too. I want an "X" if the duplication contains nothing.

Of course there are a lot of other columns, for which the values doesn't matter for the duplication: it should stay the same.
I'm not sure how to explain it, but here's an example of the output I want for the input I provided:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': ["idx1", "idx1", "idx1"],
    'test_A': ["ABC", "X", "X"],
    'test_B': ["X", "X", "X"],
    'test_C': ["ABC", "XYZ", "X"],
    'test_D': ["ABC", "XYZ", "JKL"]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative, using a helper function:

```
def split(df):
    return (df.apply(lambda c: c.str.split(' / '))  # split cells
              .apply(lambda x: x.explode().reset_index(drop=True)) # explode
              .fillna({c: 'X' for c in df.filter(like='test_').columns}) # fill missing test with X
              .ffill() # fill non-test columns
            )

## single row
split(df)

## multiple rows
df.groupby('id').apply(split).droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
     id test_A test_B test_C test_D
0  idx1    ABC      X    ABC    ABC
1  idx1      X      X    XYZ    JKL
2  idx1      X      X      X    XYZ
```

output on @jezrael's better example:

```
     id test_A test_B test_C test_D
0  idx1    ABC      X    ABC    ABC
1  idx1      X      X    XYZ    JKL
2  idx1      X      X      X    XYZ
0  idx2    SSD   "ABC     aa    ABC
1  idx2      X    JKL      X    JKL
2  idx2      X    XYZ      X      X
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'id': ["idx1", 'idx0'],
    'test_A': ["ABC",'SSD' ],
    'test_B': ["X", 'ABC / JKL / XYZ'],
    'test_C': ["ABC / XYZ", 'aa'],
    'test_D': ["ABC / JKL / XYZ", 'ABC / JKL']})
```

Idea is reshape first by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), then use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and last use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with `idx` column used for sorting and last reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('id', ignore_index=False)
df1['value'] = df1['value'].str.split(' / ')
df1 = df1.explode('value').rename_axis('idx').reset_index()
g = df1.groupby(['idx','id','variable']).cumcount()

df1 = (df1.set_index([g,'idx','id','variable'])['value']
          .unstack(fill_value='X')
          .sort_index(level=1)
          .reset_index(level=2)
          .reset_index(drop=True)
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df1)
     id test_A test_B test_C test_D
0  idx1    ABC      X    ABC    ABC
1  idx1      X      X    XYZ    JKL
2  idx1      X      X      X    XYZ
3  idx0    SSD    ABC     aa    ABC
4  idx0      X    JKL      X    JKL
5  idx0      X    XYZ      X      X
```